# Are these two statements the same performance wise?

Tags: mysql, optimization, index-tuning

**Setup**

I have a combination index in table SubmissionStatus as show below.  And running a simpl query 2 different ways.

```
 KEY `Combo_Status_Type_BidID` (`fk_ActivityStatus`,`ActivityType`,`fk_BidIDAssigned`),
```

**Query 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM SubmissionStatus SS
WHERE fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
AND ActivityType = 61
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM SubmissionStatus SS
WHERE ActivityType = 61
AND fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
```

**My understanding**

From my understanding the index I have in place here should benefit Query 1 because it has fk_ActivityStatus first, and ActivityType second, just as the Where/And conditions are listed in the statement.

**Question**

But, Is query 2 also getting to take full advantage of this index?  Or does the fact that it has ActivityType listed first prevent it from being able to use the combo Index?  (Making it having to do a full table scan, or look for an index that has ActivityType as the first.)

**P.S.**

The data table are currently to small to be able to get much reliable feedback from the EXPLAIN, and execution plan.

Comment: They're logically equivalent, so the optimiser should pick the same plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of `ANDs` in a `WHERE` clause does not matter.
The order of columns in an `INDEX` does matter.

See [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) for more discussion of indexes.

For small tests, use the Handler trick:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

When comparing two possible selects and/or indexes, the sizes of the handler numbers give a pretty reliable clue, even for small tables.

Comment: Thank you for the concise direct answer...   Nice suggestion on the handler too.  I may have to look into using that.   P.S. further testing has also confirmed your answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official MySQL Documentation ([How MySQL Optimizes WHERE Clauses](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html)) MySQL will optimize the WHERE clause as follows:

> Each table index is queried, and the best index is used unless the optimizer believes that it is more efficient to use a table scan. At one time, a scan was used based on whether the best index spanned more than 30% of the table, but a fixed percentage no longer determines the choice between using an index or a scan. The optimizer now is more complex and bases its estimate on additional factors such as table size, number of rows, and I/O block size.

(Please read the full documentation)

There is a small disclaimer at the top of the article which states:

> Note:  
> Because work on the MySQL optimizer is ongoing, not all of the optimizations that MySQL performs are documented here.

Based on the quoted article MySQL should run both statements using the same execution plan and the supplied index.